# Get Map of properties from spring-boot Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have such a problem: mine application works with set of other applications. Each of them has some unique property - templateProject-id. So, `application.properties` looks like

```
mine.application.basic-project-id.application_1=10200
mine.application.basic-project-id.application_2=10202
mine.application.basic-project-id.application_3=10001
```

I don't want to store Environment object in my service class. Only `Map<String, Long>` for pairs (application_name, project_id)
So, from that example should contain pairs `("application_1", 10200L), ("application_2",10202L), ("application_3",10001")`.

Right now I store `Environment` and with application name I build property name each time and retrieve value.

```
String projectIdPropertyName = String.format("mine.application.basic-project-id.%s", applicationDescriptor.getName());
String softwareBasicProjectId = Long.valueOf(environment.getProperty(projectIdPropertyName));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
@ConfigurationProperties("mine.application")
public class ApplicationProperties {

   private Map<String,Long> basicProjectId = new HashMap<>();

   public Map<String,Long> getBasicProjectId() { 
     return basicProjectId;
   }
}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationProperties.class)
public class YourApp { .... }
```

Then anywhere you need that stuff, just inject `ApplicationProperties`. If you enable the [Spring Boot configuration meta-data annotation processor to your build](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) you'll also get content assistance for that key (and any other key you'd add in that class).

Comment: wouldn't the `basicProjectId` always be empty?

Comment: I tried the same logic before asking question inside my service and Map finally was empty.
I tried your answer and it works. Magic

Comment: Well I wrote that code in SO without trying so I am glad it does. You need to compare this code with yours to understand what went wrong for you.